# ¿Por qué usar :before en lista con style none?

Tags: html, css, css3

Vi este código y no entiendo el porqué primero remueve el estilo y luego lo agrega con el `:before`.

1. Si remueve el style none sería lo mismo
2. ¿El `:before` no sería de más?

Ya que sin el aplicando solo el estilo funcionaría también, ¿no?

Tuve un examen y esa parte no la pude responder:

> The "content" CSS property can be used to add content to the HTML
>   document. This should be used sparingly, as CSS is not designed to add
>   content, but to style it. In some cases though it makes stylistic
>   sense to add content — for example, adding a bullet point symbol
>   before each item in an unordered list (which most browsers do by
>   default), or by automatically adding the URL of a link directly after
>   the link title.
>
> In the below example, complete the CSS rule so that a hyphen is added
>   instead of a bullet point before a list item:
>
> ```
> li {
>     list-style-type:circle (correct answer: none);
> }
>
> li:before {
>     content : "• (correct answer: -)";
>     padding-right: 8px;
> }
> ```

También lo he visto en otro código de W3Schools que aplica lo mismo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      /* Remove list bullets */
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      padding-left: 16px;
    }
    
    li:before {
      content: "•";
      /* Insert content that looks like bullets */
      padding-right: 8px;
      color: blue;
      /* Or a color you prefer */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

¿Por qué hacer eso? ¿Cuál es la necesidad si solo el estilo funcionaría también?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta una cosa: las maneras de estilizar una lista son limitadas. Con `list-style` puedes *solamente* determinar tres aspectos:

- La apariencia de la lista (`list-style-type`),
- Si es una imagen (`list-style-image`), o
- La posición de la marca (`list-style-position`).

Pero eso no puede ser suficiente para algunos casos. Por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa si quieres que la marca de lista sea de un color diferente al texto? (el ejemplo que pone W3Schools) ¿o un tamaño diferente? ¿o que esté a la derecha en lugar de la izquierda? ¿o a ambos lados?

Esos casos no son tan sencillos (o directamente no se pueden realizar) simplemente con el CSS de una lista, y es ahí donde usar un `:before` (o `:after`) para estilizar un `li` puede tener ventajas; porque es más flexible, fácil de personalizar y no está tan limitado.

Con `:before` y `:after` tienes mucha flexibilidad: posicionamiento, tamaño, color, color de fondo, imágenes, uso de contadores CSS, uso de data-atributos... ¡o todo al mismo tiempo!

Algunos ejemplos que no se pueden hacer estilizando las listas con CSS:

**Listas de diferente color al texto**
La marca de la lista tendrá el mismo color que el texto del `li`. Pero si usas `:before` puedes cambiar el color al que quieras.

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  color: red;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Elemento 1</li>
  <li>Elemento 2</li>
</ul>
```

**Listas con marcadores a ambos lados**
Con los estilos por defecto de lista sólo puedes tener una marca (incluso si haces algún "truco" en HTML para que aparezca a la derecha). Si quieres tener dos puedes usar `:before` y `:after`, e incluso las podrías hacer diferentes.

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
}

li::before,
li::after {
  content: "•";
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Elemento 1</li>
  <li>Elemento 2</li>
</ul>
```

**Listas dinámicas consecutivas y no contiguas**
Sé que esto es un caso extremo, pero podría darse. Imagina que tienes una serie de listas ordenadas que deben seguir un orden continuo, pero que están separadas en diferentes secciones.

Esto se podría hacer usando el atributo `start`, pero si el número de elementos de la lista es variable/dinámico y desconocido, podría ser complicado y perderse el orden. Es más sencillo usar `:before` y los contadores CSS para que se encarguen de eso.

```js
function nuevoApartado() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = "Apartado nuevo";
  document.getElementById("ol-1").appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: apartados;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: apartados;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(apartados) ".";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nuevoApartado()">
Nuevo Apartado en Primera Sección
</button>

<h2>Sección 1</h2>
<ol id="ol-1">
  <li>Apartado</li>
  <li>Apartado</li>
</ol>

<h2>Sección 2</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Apartado</li>
  <li>Apartado</li>
  <li>Apartado</li>
</ol>

<h2>Sección 3</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Apartado</li>
  <li>Apartado</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: li {
  list-style:none;
  color: red;
}

li{
  content: "•";
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: blue;
}
<ul>
  <li>Elemento 1</li>
  <li>Elemento 2</li>
</ul>    esto daria el mismo resultado sin el before, sigo sin entender su utilizacion ahi, o tal vez solo como ejemplo pero gracias igualmente!

Comment: @PatricioMartin No da el mismo resultado que con el `:before`. Con el `:before` el texto se ve rojo y el círculo azul. Sin el `:before` no hay círculo y todo se ve azul https://jsfiddle.net/o2nmc1rs/

Comment: @PatricioMartin La idea es que el color de la marca de lista (el circulito/cuadrado/número/lo que sea) siempre va a coincidir con el color del `li`. Para poder personalizarlo, en lugar de usar el `list-style-type`, usa el `:before` que sí te permite tener colores diferentes. Si no me he explicado bien o tienes alguna duda, ponla por aquí e intentará ayudarte.

Comment: entendi gracias, ya que no puede poseer el mismo color si no se usa el :before ! gracias !; D