# ¿Como cambiar estilo de lista con ::before?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo una pregunta sobre como poner un `list-style:;` con `::before`.

Me refiero a cambiar el circulo de una lista desordenada por un icono diferente con `::before`

Comment: Agrega el codigo que has intentado para ayudarte de una mejor forma.

Comment: Hay una pregunta parecida en el sitio, aunque está escrita desde un enfoque diferente (algo como ¿por qué hacerlo así?), creo que podría ser de ayuda. Voy a buscarla y la enlazo.

Comment: Ésta es la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/119464/250

Comment: Si tu idea era usar FontAwesome ponelo en la pregunta. No es un dato menor.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la propiedad list-style que tiene CSS sin utilizar before para personalizar el icono:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: square">
<ul style="list-style-type: disc">
<ul style="list-style-type: circle">
```

o si necesitas un icono personalizado utiliza una imagen como icono con `list-style-image`:

```
ul { 
    list-style-image: url("imagenes/icono.png");
}
```

> Aqui más información: [Listas personalizadas](http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_9.html)

usando **FontAwesome** utilizando `content` y su valor unicode:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
li:before {
  content: "\f01c"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bueno es una buena forma pero lo que busco es agregar una fuente de fontawesome para que este como formato de lista.

Comment: Edité la respuesta, compruébalo.

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '×';
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
li {
    text-indent: -0.75em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Texto corto</li>
    <li>texto largo para probar el salto de línea, lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
    <li>Otra línea</li>
</ul>
```

[JS bin](https://jsbin.com/zakoripuvi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Las publicaciones que son solo código, aunque puedan servir para resolver el problema, se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade una pequeña descripción de qué es lo que hace este código o cómo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue la siguiente:

```css
 footer .enlaces .contenedor .lista ul li::before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: '\f054';
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      color: #0f0f19;
      margin-right: 5px; 
}
```